# Using bin/rails test with 'structure.sql' instead of 'schema.rb'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a standard rails api app that I'm trying to test. I'm using structure.sql, since I chose the rails route instead of firebase/firestore for data integrity with postgres triggers, enum types, things that don't go well with schema.rb.

I'm just using the test boilerplate that comes with the rails generate, however, bin/rails test brings:

```
/Users/sebastorama/ruby/elpesador_rails/db/schema.rb doesn't exist yet. Run `rails db:migrate` to create it, then try again. If you do not intend to use a database, you should instead alter /Users/sebastorama/ruby/elpesador_rails/config/application.rb to limit the frameworks that will be loaded
```

I have `config.active_record.schema_format = :sql` on my `config/application.rb`. I searched a lot on the web, not a single clue how to do this. Any thoughts?

Comment: Did you run `rails db:migrate`?

Comment: Yep, it creates the ```structure.sql``` file. Also my test database is created correctly, I inspected it with pgAdmin. The ```bin/rails test``` command looks for the ```schema.rb```, but it shouldn't, since I'm using ```schema_format = :sql```

Comment: Weird. You could try to run `bin/rails db:test:prepare`.

Comment: No success either =/

Comment: Just to make sure: your `test.rb` environment file isn't specifying another `schema_format`, right? A thing we had to do in one project was `db:create db:structure:load db:test:prepare` in that order, before running tests; I can't remember why.

Comment: I don’t think I’m having problems with the setup per se. The problem is probably the rails test script that is looking for the schema.rb instead of structure.sql. I’ll try to setup rspec when I have some time to see if I can fiddle with rails load process.